# Translating Java to X10

Tags: java, x10-language

I'm translating a Java program into X10 and have run into a couple problems that I was wondering if anyone could help me translate.

Here's one Java segment that I'm trying to translate:

```
ArrayList<Posting>[] list = new ArrayList[this.V];
for (int k=0; k<this.V; ++k) {
    list[k] = new ArrayList<Posting>();
}
```

And here's what I've done in X10:

```
var list:ArrayList[Posting]=new ArrayList[Posting](this.V);
for (var k:int=0; k<this.V; ++k) {
    list(k)=new ArrayList[Posting]();
}
```

The line that's generating a mess of error statements is this:

```
list(k)=new ArrayList[Posting]();
```

Any suggestions and maybe an explanation on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong?  Is there a compiler error or runtime error message you can list?

Comment: I don't know if you noticed this, but `ArrayList<Posting>[] list = new ArrayList[this.V];` is an **array of `ArrayList`s** (terrible Java code btw). I don't know x10, but after browsing a bit online it doesn't look like you translated it quite right...

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with trutheality.  You need to define `list` as something like `Rail[ArrayList[Posting]]` :

```
var list:Rail[ArrayList[Posting]]=new Rail[ArrayList[Posting]](this.V);
```

Also, as X10 supports type inference for immutable variables, it's often better to use `val` instead of `var` and omit the type declaration altogether:

```
val list = new Rail[ArrayList[Posting]](this.V);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that should work for you:

```
val list = new Rail[ArrayList[Posting]](this.V);
for (k in 1..(this.V)) {
  list(k)=new ArrayList[Posting]();
}
```

And you can also do

```
val list = new Rail[ArrayList[Posting]](this.V, (Long)=>new ArrayList[Temp]());
```

i.e. use a single statement to create an initialized array.